# updating multiple different array object elements in mongodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**mongodb collection:**

```
 "_id": ObjectId("5e2ac528e9d99f3074f31de7"),
"publications": [ 
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e2ac528e9d99f3074f31de8"), 
     "name": "Times of India", 
     "productCode": "TCE1", 
     "tradeCopies": 40
  }, 
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e2ac528e9d99f3074f31de9"),  
    "publicationName": "Economic Times",  
    "productCode": "ECE1", 
    "tradeCopies": 100
  }
],
"orderCreatedBy": ObjectId("5e2977e1cc1208c65c00648b"),
"submittedTo": ObjectId("5e2555363405363bc4bf86c2"),
```

**Nodejs Code**

i would get multiple "productCode" like "TCE1","ECE1" etc,and **i need to update tradeCopies of all the object array elements in one go according to their productCodes**

**Here is what i tried**

```
exports.editOrder = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { orderId, dealerId, productCode, tradeCopies } = req.body;
try{
    const orders: await Order.updateOne(
          { _id: orderId, 
    submittedTo: dealerId,
    "publications.productCode": productCode},
    {$set:{"publications.$.tradeCopies":50}}
    )
    res.status(200).json({
          orders,
          message: "order submitted"
        });
      } catch (error) {
        res.send(error);
      }
    };
```

**CONCERNS**

1-this query is updating only 1 array object element according to the matched productCode i want all the tradeCopies of all the array objects according to their productCodes to be updated in onego

2- the above query is working only in mongo Shell not in nodejs driver and whenever i remove double quotes in nodejs query vscode shows there might an error

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/).

```
const orders: await Order.updateOne(
      {  _id: orderId, 
         submittedTo: dealerId,
         "publications.productCode": productCode
      },
      { $set: { "publications.$[element].tradeCopies":50 } },
      { arrayFilters: [ { "element.productCode": productCode } ] }
)
```

I'm not sure what you mean by removing the double quotes, but this snippet is nodejs driver compatible.

Comment: actually its updating only one object array element in mongoshell and its not working in nodejs see my postman request and its response: –  :POSTMAN ... { "orderId":"5e26be38c13b7149d0a95111","submittedTo":"5e2555363405363bc4bf86c2", "vendorOrder":[{ "productCode":"TCE1", "tradeCopies":40 }, { "productCode":"ECE1", "tradeCopies":4 } ] } POSTMAN__RESPONSE: { "orders": { "n": 0, "nModified": 0, "ok": 1 }, }  @tom slabbaert

Comment: The syntax is fine, is just seems the query isn't matched most likely due to your `odderId` and `dealerId` being type string and not objectID

Comment: i did convert them manually in my query ,,  _id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(orderId),
submittedTo: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(dealerId), POSTMAN RESPONSE is still same: { "orders": { "n": 0, "nModified": 0, "ok": 1 }, }

Comment: Is productCode also suppose to be objectID?